# React Native GraphQL $id not provided

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

I'm facing a problem concerning passing an argument to graphql query.
the id variable I take it from redux state and put it navigation params inside componentDidMount function

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if( this.props.accountReducer.hasOwnProperty('account')) {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ id: this.props.accountReducer.account._id });
    }
  }
```

the fetch query is inside a compose function.

```
    const postsQuery = graphql(fetchQuery, 
        { options: own => { const { params = {} } = own.navigation.state; return { variables: { id: params.id } }; }, 
        props: ({ data: { loading, article } }) => ({ loading, article }) });
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => { return state; }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { return bindActionCreators({ clear, connected, download }, dispatch); }
const connection = connect(mapStateToProps,  mapDispatchToProps);
const final = compose(postsQuery, connection)(ProfileScreen);
export { final as ProfileScreen };
```

and the Fetch query for user posts is:
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

```
export const fetchQuery = gql`
    query article($id: String!) {
        article(id: $id) {
            description,
            account { id, email }
        }
    }
`;
```

and the error that shows on my console is:
[image: error image]

Comment: Try returning `return {  id: params.id };` instead of `return { variables: { id: params.id } };`. You are possibly nesting the id inside the variables field instead of putting at the top level

Comment: Still it doesn't work, on my server I get the argument,  and I get result ! but graphql indicates still not working ! I get the error at component when mouting, but after that everything works fine !